# WebDriver IE9 - Strange difference in findElement() vs findElements()

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, internet-explorer-9

I'm facing an issue which appears to be somewhat strange.

On my HTML page, I have a few links

```
<a class='top 1'><img src='something.png' alt='Link 1'/></a>
<a class='top 2'><img src='something.png' alt='Link 2'/></a>
<a class='top 3'><img src='something.png' alt='Link 3'/></a>
```

Among these three, there are many other links that I'm not interested in.
My requirement is to get all these three links and do something with them. This is my code

```
List<WebElement> topLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' top ')]"));
```

Now, as far as I know, this code has two possible outcomes.

1. If any matches are found, then the size of topLinks would be let's say 3 (in my case)
2. If no matches are found, then I would get 0 as the size of topLinks list.

But when I run this code, I get an Exception, which I did not expect. I got this exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Finding elements with xpath == //a[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' top ')]returned an unexpected error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Now here is what I would like to understand:

1. Why did I get the exception? Because I have seen lots of other cases where Selenium wil not throw a NoSuchElementException in findElements() and rather just return an empty list in case of no matches being found.
2. I tried the same piece of code to substitue the findElements() with findElement(), like the snippet below, and it worked

   ```
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' top ')]"));
   ```
3. I even tried a lot of other options, like below

   ```
   List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
   ```

   The above one gavethe same exception, where as, the below one succeeded

   ```
   WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a"));
   ```

I'm sure I'm missing something here, but I don't know what. Can any one help me?

Below is the specifications I'm using:

1. Selenium build 2.39.0 (selenium-java-2.39.0.jar)
2. IE9, Windows 7 (32-Bit)
3. IEDriverServer.exe (tried and got same results on both 2.45.0 and 2.47.0 - still trying out various other combinations)

Has this got anything to do with the version combinations?

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: Can you please try it in Firefox. This is working perfectly in my end, when i did `System.out.println(topLinks.size());`, it printed `3`. I'm using `Selenium 2.45`

Comment: Thanks  for the quick response, but unfortunately my application doesn't run on any browser other than IE9. Hence I won't be able to try on any other browser. In addition to that, I can see that this works on other applications on IE9 perfectly fine.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please share the Selenium code that you've written, so that i can have a look and debug where the issue is.